# Invalid API SCHEMA for webpack devtool

Tags: webpack, react-18

I am new to webpack, please help me with this problem! I got this error once I npm audited a fix, and I have problems with eslint still. I am using react 18 from react 16 now. I have posted the webpack config file, package.json and the error below. I am not sure what other details to add, but I get this error when using the command webpack -d --watch.

webpack version: 5

````
 Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.

\```
var path = require('path');
var SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/src');
var DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/public');

module.exports = {
  entry: `${SRC_DIR}/index.jsx`,
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: DIST_DIR
  },
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  resolve: {
    // ... rest of the resolve config
    fallback: {
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify")
    }
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : SRC_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react']
        }
      }
    ]

  },
  stats: 'verbose'
};
````

package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "http://mobin0.github.io/mobin0",
  "name": "Mobin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Website",
  "author": "Mobin Skaria",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.13.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "react-dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "server-dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "seed": "node db/createDB.js",
    "test:client": "jest --watchAll --expand --verbose",
    "test:coverage": "jest --verbose --coverage",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build"
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "./client/src/tests"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.2",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "jest-dom": "^2.1.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-config-hackreactor": "git://github.com/reactorcore/eslint-config-hackreactor.git",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "express": "^4.15.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "file-system": "^1.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.1",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.6.1",
    "react-testing-library": "^5.2.3",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.83.0",
    "sinon": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details.
What version of webpack are you using?
Please share your package.json file.

Comment: @Sultan hey! I added more details, please let me know what I should do! I even tried making a new project and encountered the same problem with webpack

Comment: Sorry..I missed the notification.
Can you try without the -d file?
Or share the git repo and I can take a look.